# can't insert current file name in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

using notepad++ v6.2.3

when I tried to use TextFx->TexFx Insert->I:Current Full Path, it only insert ONE char into the editor. Same issue for inserting "current file name" or "current directory". how to solve this?

I can use Edit->Copy to clipboard, it just needs more keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always right-click on the tab and get the file path from there? quicker..

Comment: thanks. I will use this alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can't record that command in a macro, you have to use Edit>Copy to Clipboard instead. See https://superuser.com/questions/299796/

Comment: I saw that one. but I am not using Macro. I am using the menu in TextFX.